# Swift Equatable Struct doesn't allow updating?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to understand Equatable. When I using `Equatable` on my CreateCustomer struct why can I not add more phone types if I set one, or when I have added more why can I only set one? Without `Equatable` on my struct it works fine.

Here is my SwiftUI view to set the phone type

```
struct T01: View{
    @State var phoneTypes: [String] = ["Other", "Home", "Service", "Work", "Cell"]
    @State var customerCreate: CreateCustomer = CreateCustomer()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if (customerCreate != CreateCustomer()){
                Button(action: {
                    customerCreate = CreateCustomer()
                }, label: {
                    Text("Clear").padding()
                })
            }
            ForEach($customerCreate.phone.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                Menu {
                    ForEach(phoneTypes, id: \.self){ client in
                        Button() {
                            let x = client
                            customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType = x
                            print(customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType)
                        } label:{
                            Text(client)
                            if customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType == client
                            {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Text(customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType.isEmpty ? "Select the phone type *" : customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType)
                                .foregroundColor(customerCreate.phone[i].phoneType.isEmpty ? .gray : .black)
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                customerCreate.addPhone()
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                    Text("Add Phone")
                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                        .font(.system(size: 15))
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

struct CreateCustomer: Codable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CreateCustomer, rhs: CreateCustomer) -> Bool {
        // It can be fixed by changing == to > but I want the == so I can know if I should display the clear button or not.
        return String(lhs.phone.first?.phoneType ?? "") == String(rhs.phone.first?.phoneType ?? "")
    }
    
    var phone: [CustomerPhone]
    init() {
        phone = [CustomerPhone()]
    }
    public mutating func addPhone(){
        phone.append(CustomerPhone())
    }
}

struct CustomerPhone: Codable {
    var phone: String
    var phoneType: String
    init(){
        phone = ""
        phoneType = ""
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: A few things before trying to answer the question. Using Swift coding conventions makes your code easier to read, so use UpperCamelCase for names of types and protocols and lowerCamelCase for everything else (and snake case nowhere). So `customerCreate` rather `Customer_Create`, `var phone: String` rather than `var Phone: String`, etc. Also, please just use the minimal code that demonstrates the problem, and make sure it compiles (the code above doesn't). For help see [mcve]

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks, I tried to make it more minimal. It seems to only be an error when there is a struct within another struct which does make the code a little confusing to read.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your code, for instance `customerCreate != CreateCustomer()` and `phone.append(CustomerPhone())`. Why are you creating new objects in so many places?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `customerCreate != CreateCustomer()` This checks the local object against an empty to determine if the clear button should be visable which needs `Equatable `. While `phone.append(CustomerPhone())` is supposed to add a new customer phone to the array and only works without `Equatable`. I'll try to add some comments in.

Comment: That is IMO not a good way to do it, better than to have a computed property or function that returns a boolean whether the object is empty or not.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks! Sounds good, I'll do that and remove `Equatable`. Still interesting that adding `Equatable` breaks it's functionality.

Comment: `indices` and rages are unsafe in SwiftUI, you should use the objects themselves and conform to `Identifiable`

Comment: Isn’t the `ForEach($customerCreate.phone.indices)` totally broken? I can’t test it right now, but I would expect it to only update its view contents when the number of items change (which causes the indices to change), but not when any of the entries change in-place

Comment: @Alexander yeah the `Equatable` `static func == (lhs: CreateCustomer, rhs: CreateCustomer)` seems to be breaking updating, so I changed it to use `var isEmpty: Bool` like the solution and now it works fine :)

Comment: @micah do you understand what Equatable conformance does here? I think there is a missing piece that’s causing you some confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would implement Customer and CustomerPhone and how to check if a Customer object is empty

```
struct Customer: Codable, Equatable {
    var phones: [CustomerPhone]

    init() {
        phones = [CustomerPhone()]
    }

    public mutating func add(phone: CustomerPhone = CustomerPhone()){
        phones.append(phone)
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        phones.isEmpty || phones.allSatisfy(\.isEmpty)
    }
}

struct CustomerPhone: Codable, Equatable {
    var phone: String
    var phoneType: String
    init(){
        phone = ""
        phoneType = ""
    }

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        phone.isEmpty && phoneType.isEmpty
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I didn't know you could make Equatable without `static func == (lhs: CreateCustomer, rhs: CreateCustomer)`, super cool!!!!!

Comment: @micah in certain cases, the compiler can automatically synthesize the equality operator for structs and enums.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of tidying up and renaming, and making `Customer` an `ObservableObject`, I think this does what you want…

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var phoneTypes: [String] = ["Other", "Home", "Service", "Work", "Cell"]
    @StateObject var customer = Customer()
        
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if !customer.isEmpty {
                Button(action: {
                    customer.phones = []
                }, label: {
                    Text("Clear").padding()
                })
            }
            ForEach($customer.phones.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                Menu {
                    ForEach(phoneTypes, id: \.self) { phoneType in
                        Button() {
                            customer.phones[i].phoneType = phoneType
                            
                            print(customer.phones)
                        } label:{
                            Text(phoneType)
                            if customer.phones[i].phoneType == phoneType {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    VStack{
                        HStack{
                            Spacer()
                            Text(customer.phones[i].phoneType.isEmpty ? "Select the phone type *" : customer.phones[i].phoneType)
                                .foregroundColor(customer.phones[i].phoneType.isEmpty ? .gray : .black)
                            Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                customer.addPhone()
                
                print(customer.phones)
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                    Text("Add Phone")
                        .fontWeight(.thin)
                }
            })
            .font(.system(size: 15))
        }
    }
}

final class Customer: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var phones: [CustomerPhone]
    
    var isEmpty: Bool {
        phones == [CustomerPhone()]
    }
    
    init() {
        phones = [CustomerPhone()]
    }
    
    public func addPhone(){
        phones.append(CustomerPhone())
    }    
}
```